# My elements will only appear (sometimes) after hot reloading, but not in first load

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a file called `SpecPlayer.vue` where I'm using a component (`SpecChampionData`) and the component will only appear after hot reloading (not always, sometimes), but not after the first load.

I'm new to Vue and I don't use TS or JS in a daily basis, so please try to answer as completely as possible, so I can understand what's **actually** happening here.

[image]

As you can see, the component is somewhat **partially** loaded.

This is how I'm using it:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as art from '@/getArt'
import SpecChampionData from './SpecChampionData.vue'
import { Player } from '@/types/ddata'

defineProps<{
    player: Player | undefined
}>()
</script>
<template>
    <div class="w-full p-4 rounded-md bg-semi">
        <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 flex-nowrap">
            <div class="relative h-20 border-2 aspect-square avatar border-primary">
                <div>
                    <div v-if="player?.isDead"
                        class="absolute inset-0 z-20 flex items-center justify-center aspect-square h-full text-[#ff0000]">
                        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">{{ Math.ceil(player.respawnTimer || 0) }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <img v-if="player?.championName" class="avatar" :class="{
                        'grayscale brightness-50': player?.isDead
                    }" :src="art.getChampIcon(player?.championName)">
                    <img v-else src="/BigFist.png" class="grayscale">
                    <div
                        class="absolute bottom-0 w-7 left-[50%] z-10 translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[50%] bg-semi border-2 border-primary rounded-full aspect-square flex justify-center items-center">
                        <h1 class="text-sm font-medium text-center text-white">{{ player?.level || 0 }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold text-primary">{{ player?.summonerName || 'Jugador' }}</h1>
                <h1 class="text-white">{{ player?.championName }} <h1 v-if="player?.skinName"> ({{ player?.skinName }})
                    </h1>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Here is the component -->
        <SpecChampionData :player="player"></SpecChampionData>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is the component itself:

```html
<template>
    <h1>{{ champData?.lore }}</h1>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios'
import { Champion, ChampionResponse, Player } from '@/types/ddata'
import { Ref, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{
    player: Player | undefined
}>()
const champData: Ref<Champion | undefined> = ref()

const champName = props.player?.championName

axios.get(`https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/14.5.1/data/es_AR/champion/${champName}.json`)
    .then(res => {
        const resData: ChampionResponse = res.data
        if (champName) {
            champData.value = resData.data[champName]
        }
    })
</script>
```

I've tried restarting the host, and using `onBeforeMount`/`onMounted`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have any message on the console ? Also have you tried in a different browser, cleaning cache etc ?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your component (sometimes) loads on hot reload indicates that the `props.player` is not being passed through properly.

So here's what happens chronologically -

1. `SpecPlayer.vue` gets mounted with with `props.player` value being undefined, because in your parent component you didn't wait for `player` value to be available before calling `SpecPlayer.vue`.
2. `props.player` with value `undefined` gets propagated further down to `SpecChampionData.vue` and axios fails because champion with name `undefined` doesn't exist, which is why your component doesn't load properly.
3. While all of this is happening, player value became available but all the other components are mounted already.
4. When you update something and it hot reloads, since `player` value became available in the meantime, it propagates properly and the component loads.

To combat this, make sure you only load component if you have all the necessary data for the component to work.

In the parent of `SpecPlayer.vue`, make sure to only load `SpecPlayer` component if you have player available like so -

```js
  <SpecPlayer v-if="player" :player="player" />
```

This will ensure that `<SpecPlayer />` component will load only if player is available.

If player is only required for `SpecChampionData.vue`, then move the if statement further down the chain -

```js
  <SpecChampionData v-if="player" :player="player" />
```

**TLDR** - You didn't wait for data to be loaded before calling the component and axios is trying to fetch undefined.

Comment: I was just about to try this, and It works! Thank you very much for the detail